# GraphQL query use nested objects` fields to filter

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I just started to learn graphql and HotChocolate.Data in .net core.
I usind attribute [UseFiltering]
How do I use nested objects` fields to filter rows from a table and also filter the nested objects as well?

```
query GetData(
  $search: String
) {
  documents(
    where: {
       name: { contains: $search }
    }
  ) {
    total: totalCount
    items {
      id
      name
      requirements(
        where: {
          name: { contains: $search }
        }
      ) 
      {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Filtering by documents works fine, but if I try to connect the filtering by requirements I get errors
Error during generation:  Unknown argument "where" on field "Document.requirements".

Comment: I found that I had to add the `[UseFiltering]` attribute to the collection property of the class (i.e. your `requirements` property

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to tell HotChocolate that you want to filter on that field. [As Chris says in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71602542/graphql-query-use-nested-objects-fields-to-filter#comment126777400_71602542), you can use annotation to do this with `[UseFiltering]`

Alternatively, you can use a code-first approach:

In your `Item` type, you should add `UseFiltering()` to the `Requirements` field:

```
protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Item> descriptor)
{
    descriptor
        .Field(x => x.Requirements)
        .UseFiltering(); // This is the relevant line to add
}
```